# Why does jQuery animate not work on mobile devices if viewport is present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

So the following works fine on my webpage on Desktop but doesn't cause any scroll on Mobile...

```
 $("HTML, BODY").animate({
        scrollTop: 500
    }, 1000);
```

[This post](http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-on-mobile-devices-iphone-ipad-android-phones/) seems to suggest it has something to do with mobile devices not scrolling on body but on viewport instead. And if I remove this viewport tag from my page then the scroll does work....

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But I have seen pages where the viewport tag is present but the animation works, so what gives?

Comment: Hard to tell you why without any more context. I use jQuery animate all the time and have never had an issue on mobile, `viewport` tag or not. However, the resource you linked says to use `$("body")` instead of `$("html, body")` - have you tried this?

Comment: what mobile browser you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem as he described. I'm using this:

```
$(".buttonTop").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".bestline").offset().top},
      1300);
});
```

And as he described, when removing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Things start working. And it's not related to mobile device or browser because it happends in Chrome console too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using a hamburger menu when the windows width is under 930px. Below this limit, the scroll were broken because I needed to make the site-content scroll instead of the body :

```
var page = $('#myAnchor'); // target page
var speed = 750; // animation (ms)

if ($( window ).width() <= 930 ){
        $('.site-content').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top }, speed );
}
else {
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top }, speed, function(){//calback} ); // Go 
    }
```